# Inconsistent addEventListerner behaviour angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener

I am using `innerHTML` binding to create dynamic `a` tag as in below code:

```
<span *ngIf="msg" [innerHTML]="msg | sanitizeHtml"></span>
```

In .ts I am trying to add click event using `addEventListerner`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.tradebtn');
  if (this.elements && this.elements.length > 0) {
    this.elements.forEach((f) => {
      console.log(f)
      f.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.log(event)
      });
    });
   }
}
```

I get `elements`elements` list to add event listener. Click event listener works sometimes but doesn't work at most of the times.

I am perplexed at this behavior. I also tried to enclose the code `setTimeout()` but no luck.

Comment: what does the `span` have to do with the code? are elements with class `tradebtn` created dynamically perhaps, after the `querySelectorAll` has run? What are the elements with class `tradebtn`? Are they buttons inside a form?

Comment: @JaromandaX `span` is just a parent element to set its `innerHTML`. Yes `tradebtn` is the `a` tag created dynamically. When I console.log(elements) I do get all my dynamically created `a` tags.

Comment: OK, so what "doesn't work" means

Comment: @JaromandaX the click event using `addEventListener`

Comment: so, no errors in the console? if you inspect the element in developer tools, does it have an event handler attached?

Comment: @JaromandaX no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@HostListener` to handle event.

Add condition `event.target.matches('.tradebtn')` to check element source.

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
   onclick(event) {
   if(event.target.matches('.tradebtn')) {
        console.log(event)
   }
}
```

Comment: This works thanks! Not sure why my approach wouldn't work.